# Smallest subgroup of $S_4$ containing a set of permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

So the question asks to find the order of the smallest subgroup of $S_4$ (call this subgroup $G$) which contains the following set of permutations:
$$\{ (12)(34),(14)(32),(24),(31) \}$$

I know that since the order of $S_4$ is 24, the order of $G$ must divide 24.

I also have that the identity element is included in $G$ so the order of $G$ must be at least $5$ which limits the possible orders to: $6$, $8$, $12$, and $24$.

In a similar question I had that all the permutations were even so could use that it was in $A_4$ but that won't work here. Any tips or tricks I can use to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to write $(24)(13)$ instead of having a comma separate them?

Comment: No the question puts them as separate permutations.

Comment: "I also have that the identity element is included in $G$ so this limits the possible orders to: $6$, $8$, $12$, and $24$." Why? The identity element is included in every subgroup of $S_4$, so this tells you nothing about its order. You can say something based on the orders of the elements you are given, though.

Comment: Well the order of the subgroup must be at least 5 so this excludes 1,2,3, and 4 as possible orders. I'll edit the question to specify this though.

Comment: @jdminer I see what you mean.

Comment: Number the vertices of a square in ccw order $1,2,3,4$ so that $1$ is in the Southeast, $2$ in NE, $3$ in NW and $4$ in SW. Then $(12)(34)$ is the reflection w.r.t. a horizontal symmetry axis, $(14)(23)$ w.r.t. a vertical symmetry axis, and the other two are reflections w.r.t. a diagonal. So... Have you heard of dihedral groups?

Comment: Continuing your original argument: the order can't be $6$, since that would require two elements of order $3$, but you have already accounted for five elements, none of which have order $3$. Since @JyrkiLahtonen has identified a subgroup of order $8$ containing all of your elements, that must be the smallest order possible.

Comment: Another useful fact: if $H$ is any subgroup of a symmetric group $S_n$, then either all of the elements of $H$ are even (i.e. elements of $A_n$), or exactly half of them are even. This gives another way to eliminate $6$ as a possible order: if $|H| = 6$, then $H$ must contain an element of order $3$ (by Cauchy's theorem), which would have to be a $3$-cycle and therefore even. You already have three even elements and two odd, so adding a $3$-cycle would give you four even and two odd, which violates the useful fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(1\ 4)(2\ 3) = (1\ 3)(2\ 4)$, it's clear your group contains:

$V = \{e, (1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 3)(2\ 4), (1\ 4)(2\ 3)\}$, which eliminates $6$ as a possible order.

Since your generated group contains odd permutations, it cannot be $A_4$, which eliminates $12$ as a possibility (as this is the only subgroup of $S_4$ of order $12$).

So we are left with just $8$ or $24$.

Finally, note that:

$(1\ 3)(1\ 2)(3\ 4) = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$, so that your generated group contains:

$D_8 = \{e, (1\ 3), (2\ 4), (1\ 3)(2\ 4), (1\ 4)(2\ 3), (1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 2\ 3\ 4), (1\ 4\ 3\ 2)\}$ (check that this is a group of symmetries of a square with vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $r = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4), s = (1\ 2)(3\ 4)$).

Since your set is completely contained in this subgroup, and $8 < 24$, we have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a Sylow 2 subgroup of $S_4$
$S_4$ has a Sylow 2 subgroup of order 8. (12)(34) and (24) generate a 4 cycle. So 4 divides the order of G. so we have (1,2)(3,4)(2,4)=(4,1,2,3) =(1,2,3,4).
But we have $(1,2)$ is not in $<(1,2,3,4)>$ thus order of the subgroup is 8,12 or 24. But we know (2,4) and (1,2,3,4) generate $D_8$ so the group generated is $D_8$ since I can express the other elements using these two generators.

Note
(1,2,3,4)(2,4)=(1,2)(3,4)
(4,3,2,1)(2,4)=(1,4)(2,3)
(1,2,3,4)²(2,4)=(1,3)

Comment: How do you know that $(12)$ is in the group?

Comment: Sorry misread the question

Comment: Yes, but all 3 are conjugate subgroups that are isomorphic to each other.